# Accessing data attributes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes, dataset

I have been using:

```
var data = element.getAttribute('data-name');
```

But it seems easier to use 'dataset'

```
var data = element.dataset.name
```

But my question is: Is there anyway I can use element.dataset with a var? For example I can't get this to work:

```
var dataName = 'test';

var data = element.dataset.dataName;
```

Comment: Presumably `element` is a DOM element, and `element.dataset` gives its `data-*` attributes. I'm not sure why you would think that it would give access to arbitrary variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what the code you wrote actually does.

`var data = element.dataset.name` is the code which works and you're familiar with – it looks for a property called `name` inside `element.dataset`. In this case, `name` is not an identifier which refers to a variable.

In exactly the same way, the code `element.dataset.dataName` looks for a property `dataName` inside `element.dataset`. `dataName` is not seen as an identifier.

What you want to do is look for a property called `test`, the content of your variable `dataName`.

To do that, you need to use bracket notation:

```js
var dataName = 'test';

var data = element.dataset[dataName];
```

Here is a working code snippet which demonstrates this method:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

var dataName = 'test';
var data = element.dataset[dataName];

console.log(data);
```

```html
<div data-test="success"></div>
```

You could also look into [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript), although many people would recommend against using them in javascript when it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I was blanking on using [] but that makes so much sense!